# Is it possible to mutate properties from an arbitrarily nested child component in vue.js without having a chain of events in the entire hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

It is mentioned in multiple places that mutating properties is an anti-pattern in `vue.js`. It warns the user not to do it, even when mutating object properties or using functions like `this.$set` to add elements to an object given as a property.

Given that, what is supposed to be the correct way of having a component responsible for modifying some data it's given? The `vue.js` suggested pattern seems to be emitting events, but consider this fictional example:

```
// Main Component
<template>
   // content skipped for simplicity
   <some-component :someObject="something" />
</template>

// SomeComponent
// Passes this data to another component
<template>
    <another-component :someObject="someObject" />
</template>

// AnotherComponent
// Does things using someObjet
```

Let's imagine that the third component, `AnotherComponent` is responsible for displaying some data that has been passed down all the way from the main UI that used a component that ended up using this one. And let's say this `AnotherComponent` maybe can even pass this data (or even some of it) to other components.

Does it mean that then, the component that will end up modifying this data (for example a delete button in a list of things) has to emit an event, and then all the components in this hierarchy have to listen to those events and emit all the way up to the original component that is the only one *actually allowed* to mutate the object?

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *not* chain events to perform parent/deep child (or do deep ancestor/sibling communication), for simple scenarios, [you can use an **event hub**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced). (For complex scenarios, see [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org).)

You would create a global variable:

```
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub
```

To emit events you would use in **any** component:

```
eventHub.$emit('myevent', 'some value');
```

You would, then, in any other component, listen to that event. The action of that event could be anything, including a function that changes the data:

```
mounted() {
    eventHub.$on('myevent', (e) => {
        console.log('myevent received', e)
        this.someDataProperty = 'newValue' + e;
    });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub

Vue.component('some-component', {
  template: "#some-component",
  props: ['someObject']
});
Vue.component('another-component', {
  template: "#another-component",
  props: ['someObject'],
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      eventHub.$emit('myevent', ' <some event value> ' + this.someObject.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: 'initial value'
  },
  created() {
    eventHub.$on('myevent', (e) => {
      this.something = 'newValue-' + e;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="some-component">
    <div>
        some-component: {{ someObject }}
        <hr>
        <another-component :some-object="someObject" />
    </div>
</template>
<template id="another-component">
    <div>
    another-component: {{ someObject }}<br>
    <button @click="myMethod">Trigger event at 3rd level that will call some-component's method</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  Parent: {{ something }}
  <hr>
  <some-component :some-object="something" />
</div>
```

**Note:** If creating a dedicated instance as event hub is something complicated in your environment, you can replace `eventHub` with `this.$root` (inside your components) and use your own Vue instance as hub.

Comment: I haven't had time to try it yet, although I suspect I will end up trying to use vuex to have something cleaner, I'll see what works best once I implement it