# Vuex model update won't reload computed property

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following component to quickly configure stops on a delivery/pickup route and how many items are picked up and dropped

[image]

and this is the data model, note the 2 is the one next to 'a' on the previous image.

[image]

If a click the + or - button, in the first item, it behaves as expected,

[image]

But second item doesn't work as expected

[image]

I've already checke a couple of posts on object property update likes this ones

[Is it possible to mutate properties from an arbitrarily nested child component in vue.js without having a chain of events in the entire hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805132/is-it-possible-to-mutate-properties-from-an-arbitrarily-nested-child-component-i)

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/nested-props-mutations-hell-internet-need-clarification/99346
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-mutating-object-props-bad-practice/17448

among others, and came up with this code:

```
ADD_ITEM_TO_SELECTED_STOP(state, payload) {
      let count = state.selectedStop.categories[payload.catIndex].items[payload.itemIndex].count;
      const selectedCat = state.selectedStop.categories[payload.catIndex];
      const currentItem = selectedCat.items[payload.itemIndex];
      currentItem.count = count + 1;
      selectedCat.items[payload.itemIndex] = currentItem;
      Vue.set(state.selectedStop.categories, payload.catIndex, selectedCat);
    },
```

and as the button event:

```
addToItem(item) {
      this.$store.dispatch("addItemToSelectedStop", {
        catIndex: item.catIndex,
        itemIndex: item.itemIndex
      })
    },
```

And finally my computed property code:

```
items() {
      let finalArray = [];
      this.selectedStop.categories.forEach(
        (cat, catIndex) => {
          let selected = cat.items.filter((item) => item.count > 0 );
          if (selected.length > 0) {
            //here we add the catIndex and itemIndex to have it calling the rigth shit
            selected = selected.map(val => {
              let itemIndex = cat.items.findIndex( itemToFind => itemToFind.id === val.id);
              return {
                ...val,
                catIndex: catIndex,
                itemIndex: itemIndex,

              }})
            finalArray = finalArray.concat(selected);
          }
        });
      return finalArray;
    }
```

What confuses me the most is that I have almost the same code in another component, and there it's working as expected, and although the model is changed, the computed property is only recalculated on the first item,

Comment: Try to reproduce the bug.

Comment: seems to be a fairly common issue with vuex related to us developers using it beyond how it was meant to be used, and ignoring the reactivity principles it's build around, finally managed to fix it, below is how it's working now on my project

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DawidMyslak/2b046cca5959427e8fb5c1da45ef7748) and taking a look again at the posts describing this kind of issue, I decided to give it a try and just make a copy of the whole stored object not just the property, update it, then set it back on vuex using Vue.set, and that did the trick, everything is now working as expected, this is my final store method.

```
ADD_ITEM_TO_SELECTED_STOP(state, payload) {
      let selectedLocalStop = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.selectedStop));
      let count = selectedLocalStop.categories[payload.catIndex].items[payload.itemIndex].count;
      selectedLocalStop.categories[payload.catIndex].items[payload.itemIndex].count = count + 1;
      Vue.set(state,"selectedStop", selectedLocalStop );
      //Now we search for this step on the main list
      const stepIndex = state.stops.findIndex(val => val.id === selectedLocalStop.id);
      Vue.set(state.stops,stepIndex, selectedLocalStop );
    },
```

I had to add the last bit after updating the whole object, because, originally, the array items were updated when the selected item was changed, I guess some sort of reference, but with the object creation, that relationship no longer works "automatic" so I need to update the array by hand

Comment: I think this may have to do with "deep" reactivity, in that vue does not react to deeply nested changes unless you explicitly tell it to. By updating the array by hand i think you trigger the reactivity because the change is happening at the top level.

Comment: exactly, the weird part, is that before changing the first section, there was no need to set the array, as the info inside was updated automatically in the vuex object, yet won't show in the UI XD at the end its a matter of avoiding any dirty reference, and always build new objects - update - set with vue.set